# list the meta data (recording date, dimensions, title, aperture options ...) of an uploaded image in php

Tags: php, image, exif

is there any possible result to list the meta data of the images? (recording date, focal length). Maybe in php?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [exif_read_data()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) function:

```
<?php
echo "img1.jpg:<br />\n";
$exif = exif_read_data('tests/img1.jpg', 'IFD0');
echo $exif===false ? "No headers.<br />\n" : "Image contains headers<br />\n";

$exif = exif_read_data('tests/img2.jpg', 0, true);
echo "img2.jpg:<br />\n";
foreach ($exif as $key => $section)
{
    foreach ($section as $name => $val)
    {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
?>
```

All the further informations bout function can be found under the link above (PHP Manual website).